# Max number of versions allowed in SDE / weird behavior with large number of versions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, versioning

Is there a maximum number of versions allowed in an enterprise geodatabase? I have an enterprise geodatabase with a default version that has about 70 child versions. I am experiencing weird behavior where children versions is pushed to the default version without me doing anything. This has happened several times, apparently randomly. I am unable to replicate it, but it happens about once a week. Note that the database is on SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Are you certain everyone is working on their own version and not on the default?

Comment: There is no limit to the number of versions in an enterprise geodatabase.  There is a limit to the number of states, but it's so large (2147483647) that it's effectively unlimited.  Versions are *unlimited* because a version is a *named state* and each version could point to the same state. Whatever is happening in your database is unrelated to any limits to versions or states.  Please **edit** the question to describe more fully how the versions are created and used, along with details about your frequency of compression and reconciliation.

Comment: @Jyler We have edits on the default and on versions. Is that not a best practice? We are using versions as 'what if' for different scenarios and pushing them at certain dates when those scenarios are approved. Immediate edits are done on the default.

Comment: Keep in mind that the versioning model utilizies a state tree.  Due to your "immediate edits", the SDE.DEFAULT version is a moving target, while the outstanding "scenarios" are linked to the state which was current when each scenarios was created.  Given the way your scenarios pin the state tree, none of the recent "immediate" edits would be visible to the scenarios, and there would be no way to post immediate edits to the business table.

Comment: @juturna Typically editors work on a version of the default and then reconcile and push edits up when they're ready to go live. This is to reduce erroneous data getting promoted to the master(default) database. Plus, people can work on the same data w/o running into a schema lock. Is your issue happening on the same day of the week?

Comment: @Jyler It doesn't happen on certain days. It is fairly sporadic - I plan on taking more careful notes about when this is happening.